# RDP to windows server 2016 not working google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rdp, windows-server-2016

My windows server 2016 is not connecting using RDP. It was working till yesterday but today it is not working. I had just rebooted the server and no other change was done. I am able to connect using Interactive Serial Console. Following are the findings:

1. Faulty server is not reachable from any other working server in the same subnet. Neither ICMP (ping) nor with TCP. For TCP, I checked with Test-NetConnection  -Port 3389 and result was a failure.
2. Surprisingly, The faulty server is able to reach other servers with ping and Test-NetConnection on port 3389.
3. RDP is in running state. Verified by sc query SessionEnv, sc query TermService, sc query UmRdpService, sc query RpcSs, sc query RpcEptMapper. All these services are running. Also, restarted services.
4. Netstat -a shows that RDP is listening on port 3389.

```
netstat -a | findstr 3389
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           IPADDRESS:0       LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:3389              IPADDRESS:0       LISTENING                
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3389           *:*
  UDP    [::]:3389              *:*
```

5. Verified No antivirus, windows firewall, security blockage.
6. Followed the steps given on https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp and output is PASSED. For NLA and SecureLayer the output was different and added the required changes to registry.

Can someone please help me to fix this? Is it possible to verify if RDP is broken?

Error screenshot when attempted RDP connect from server in same subnet:
[image]

Comment: when you say firewall, do you mean windows firewall or GCP firewall?

Comment: Did you tried the steps in the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-windows) as well?

Comment: Unless you have modified the VPC internal firewall rule, you have one of two problems: a) Windows network configuration problem; b) Windows firewall preventing remote connections. Double-check which IP address you are using to connect. When connecting from inside the same VPC network, use the private IP address. From outside the VPC use the external public IP address.

Comment: @jabbson: Windows Firewall.

Comment: @ChandraKiranPasumarti: I have tried but did not help. It has link to RDP troubleshooting. Completed all those steps but no luck.

Comment: @JohnHanley: I have made sure I use correct private IP address. Is it possible for you to point out which firewall rule(s) should i look at?

Comment: Google search for a guide on setting up the Windows Firewall for remote connections. The steps are too long to put in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

by default windows desktop is blocked and disabled by windows firewall,
follow these steps to enable it

1.Open Windows Firewall (Start button > Windows System > Control Panel) - From the Control Panel Go to Systems and Security > Windows Defender Firewall.
2.From the Firewall, Click on the Allow and app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall link in the left pane.
3.Click Change settings and then check the box next to Remote Desktop, for both private and public networks.
4.Click OK to save the new settings.

you can refer this [link](https://www.configserverfirewall.com/windows-10/enable-remote-desktop-windows-10/) for more details